# Запрос в запрос ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Правильно ли делать запрос в запросе? Мне нужно дождаться пока первы аякс запрос вернет из базы значения и срендерит инпуты и кнопки, и после этого кликая по кнопке посылаю еще один аякс запрос.

```
$('#dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var id = btn.parents('form').data('dep-id');

            $.ajax({
                url : '/settings/get_holidays',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id : id },
                success: function(data){
                    var holidaysForm = $('#holidaysFormTpl').render(data);
                    $('.display-table .tbody').append(holidaysForm);    
                    initializeDtepicker2();

                    $('.add-holiday').click(function(){
                        var btnSaveHol = $(this);

                        $.ajax({
                            url : '/settings/add_holidays',
                            method : 'POST',
                            data : btnSaveHol.parents('form').serialize(),
                            dataType : 'json',
                            success : function(data){

                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, неправильно.

Вообще, "запрос в запросе" сам по себе приемлем, но у Вас-то никакого "запроса в запросе" нет. Событие `click` новой кнопки и, соответственно, второй `ajax` запрос произойдут позднее, когда обработчик `success` первого запроса уже давно отработает. У Вас, однако, другая проблема.

Если на Вашей странице окажутся другие элементы с классом `add-holiday` (а не только новый, только что созданный), то Вы будете повторно навешивать на них дополнительные обработчики `click`, которые все будут выстреливать при нажатии этих кнопок.

Делайте такое же делегирование обработки события `click` для `'.add-holiday'` как и для `'.show-holidays'`.

```
$('#dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var id = btn.parents('form').data('dep-id');

    $.ajax({
        url : '/settings/get_holidays',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id : id },
        success: function(data){
            var holidaysForm = $('#holidaysFormTpl').render(data);
            $('.display-table .tbody').append(holidaysForm);    
            initializeDtepicker2();

        }
    });
});

$('.display-table .tbody').on('click', '.add-holiday', function(){
    var btnSaveHol = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : '/settings/add_holidays',
        method : 'POST',
        data : btnSaveHol.parents('form').serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){

        }
    });
});
```

Да, и мне кажется, что в Вашем случае больше подходит метод `jQuery` `closest`, а не `parents`.

Comment: Я не смогу навесить  клик на .add-holiday таким образом так как кнопка  появляется после первого запроса ajax, а таким образом я буду искать кнопку до того как она появилась,селектор просто не найдет ее.

Comment: @quaresma89 - А Вы попробуйте.

Comment: Работает спасибо.